# approve person identity by finger print system in php&mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fingerprint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fingerprint authentication for php web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498945/fingerprint-authentication-for-php-web-app)

i want to build system that handle saving people value stuff in special store . when any client want to save his stuff in special box system will register his fingerprint so when he want to receive his stuff system will approve his identity by his finger print .

note : that i want to save the fingerprint to the database so it can be used in another branch .. so each client need to register his fingerprint one time only . and the database will share his fingerprint ..

and if its possible that we could save his fingerprint picture this will excellent .

how could we make this true by using mysql and php and what is the best fingerprint machine could be used to handle this job ..

if there are any smaples that match my requiremts please include them .

Answer (score 0):

First, find your fingerprint scanner  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/184-0152934-3708544?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=fingerprint+scanner&x=0&y=0         http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?SearchText=fingerprint+scanner&Country=&IndexArea=product_en&fsb=y

Then study the API - that has nothing to do with what you seem to be asking here.  The API will give you some sort of data structure to represent a fungerprint. Store that as a BLOB in your database.

What more do you want to know?

Comment: thanks for reply .
i have the fingerprint scanner "digital persona model : uru4s-u1" and i install its driver .