# how to match fingerprint by using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, fingerprint

i doing project to compare finger print that is saved in mysql database. i have to check the fingerprint that is store in db with the user input fingerprint on a device.

i have check links but mostly are based on java / c# .

[1] [approve person identity by finger print system in php&mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442134/approve-person-identity-by-finger-print-system-in-phpmysql)
[2]http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/web-development/51918-fingerprint-scanner-php-mysql-db.html

kindly help me or suggest me links or algorithm to do that task .

Comment: I dont think this is possible with php...

Comment: @NishantSolanki  look:http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/ this vendor provide api for php :(

Comment: have you downloaded it???

Comment: No its paid service :(

Comment: they are providing one month for free..

Comment: do you know any algorith that will be converted into php

Comment: it depends.. what output does your `fingure print scanner` returns.. is it a `string` or an `image` or anything else..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49530/discussion-between-user3099183-and-nishant-solanki)